# Как через админку вордпресса увеличить иконку glyphicons.com/?

Tags: wordpress, icon

В theme options прописываю social-instagram, но иконка маленькая по сравнению с фейсбуком рядом.

http://joxi.ru/Dr8P4ojUkEX3Nr

http://joxi.ru/12M5ZVlt4OjYG2

http://joxi.ru/8Anbp3OHqVlM7A

Comment: Картинки вставляй в тело вопроса (хотя в даном случае они вообще не нужны). И сам вопрос должен быть в теле сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

> Как через админку вордпресса увеличить иконку

Кастомайзер (Внешний вид-настроить) - дополнительные стили.